# why is the second 'add to cart link' is hidden on ubercart/drupal site?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

My site is built on drupal using ubercart. 
I have two 'add to cart links' on my page but for some reason the second one is hidden. It only shows if i delete the first one. 
You can see them both in view source of the page. (The second button should be next to 'contact us' button)
My site is https://www.thepetwiki.com/mg-testsite.com/ubercart/painting/kaluga-dock 
any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hide it in css.

http://www.thepetwiki.com/mg-testsite.com/ubercart/sites/all/themes/NaiveArtOnlineColorful/style.css

line 2819

```
#edit-actions--2 {
    display: none;
}
```

Drupal automatically changes the id if you have multiple form items with the same id.

Comment: thank you so much, that was the issue. If drupal changes the ID how do I avoid the issue I had here, when the ID was being used for something else? Is it best to wrap a class around it then use the ID?

Comment: Just add the form id to your style to apply it to a specific form. Also, you can add a class to your form items using form_alter() I hope this helps.